# Can't deploy Django + Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

can't run Django on Heroku.

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
antiorm==1.2.1
asgiref==3.2.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
bootstrap4==0.1.0
db==0.1.1
db-sqlite3==0.0.1
Django==3.0.5
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-cleanup==4.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

This is the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath home.wsgi
```

And then the settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://deniseandrade.herokuapp.com/', '127.0.0.1']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_DIR,
)

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# My settings
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

# Heroku settings.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

How my files are organized:
[image]

Error:
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

Comment: Are you using sqlite3 in production? @Felipe Dourado

Comment: Heroku doesn't support the use of sqlite3. You have to change to postgresql. ie psycopg2

Comment: run this in your Heroku CLI `heroku logs --tail -a deniseandrade`or see logs from website `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/deniseandrade/logs`

Comment: Weird, I've been following the "Python Crash Course Book" and the author used sqlite3 and then deployed Django to Heroku in the last chapter. But anyway, despite the database, the server should run, shouldn't it?